# Class constructor UpgradeComponent cannot be invoked without 'new' after Update to Angular 10

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-hybrid

I just started to upgrade an Angular project from 9.1.0 to 10.0.12
It is still a hybrid app and has couple of components upgraded (from Angular JS) as described in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeComponent)

However after the Update to Angular 10 those upgraded components would not load and result in the following error

> Class constructor UpgradeComponent cannot be invoked without 'new' (at new MyUpgradedComponentDirective)

I searched the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and didn't found any information regarding UpgradeComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After endless search without results I went to trial & error mode.
I discovered that there is a `jit` property on the `@Directive`, if set to `true` the mentioned error goes away.

With adding `jit: true` the upgraded component code looks something like this

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'my-angular-selector',
    jit: true,
})
export class MyDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
        super('angularJsDirectiveSelector', elementRef, injector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Changing `jit` to true might be not the best solution - that will switch the directive to the mode, when it's compiled in browser runtime, instead of being served as pre-compiled JS code.

It seems like the issue described here might be solved with setting `tsconfig.json` `output` property to `ES2015` if you have older version there.

More details can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18067